# Unable to inject my provider in config

Tags: angularjs

I have `app/providers/weather.js`:

```
angular.module('forecast').provider('Weather', function() {    
  var apiKey;

  this.setApiKey = function(key) {
    if(key) apiKey = key;
  };

  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      ... // Some methods
    };
  };    
});
```

And I'm trying to inject that into my `config` block:

```
angular.module('forecast', ['ngRoute']).config(function(WeatherProvider) {    
  WeatherProvider.setApiKey('hello1234');    
});
```

However I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module forecast due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: WeatherProvider
```

The strange thing is that I can successfully inject `Weather` into the controllers and have access to the methods in `this.$get`.

My `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Forecast</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="forecast">

  <section class="content" ng-view></section>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/home.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/settings.js"></script>

  <script src="app/providers/weather.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to find out the error reason. I'm running Angular 1.2.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are working with **one** module `'forecast'`, so in this case we should/have to be sure, that the configuration already has access to the provider. Other words, set this kind of steps:

```
// I. Module creation
angular.module('forecast', ['ngRoute']) 
  // II. Provider definition
  .provider('Weather', function() {    
    ...
  }
  // III. configuration using already known provider
  .config(function(WeatherProvider) {    
    ...
  })
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your provider needs to be declared as part of the module `forecast` before you try to inject it.

One approach, that involves the least change to your current code,  is to separate out the module declaration and do it first:

```
angular.module('forecast', ['ngRoute']);
```

Then use that when you set up config:

```
angular.module('forecast').config(function(WeatherProvider) {    
  WeatherProvider.setApiKey('hello1234');    
});
```

Noting that inside your `angular.module`:

- **Without square brackets** you're accessing an existing module
- **With the square brackets** you're declaring a new module.

So you're currently declaring the module and doing the config all at once- without the provider having been instantiated.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw3yG/)